# "Creating Android project" taking forever (Cordova, ionic, Phonegap)

Tags: android, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to run 
`Cordova platform add android`
Or
    `Ionic platform add android`
Or the Phonegap counterpart, the message "Creating android project" takes literally forever, i.e the command doesn't to anything.

I'm on Windows 8 x64 and have the Java JDK 1.8 + the Android SDK installed & updated.

I'm totally lost here since I don't get any error message whatsoever and it happens with all three platforms.

Comment: Did you try verbose mode? `cordova platform add android --verbose` should reveal more debug output to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was most likely caused by a mixup of two Android SDK installations, one done by hand, one from the new Android Studio Beta. After removing one of these & fixing my environment variables, everything worked fine.